# "Code" for Chord Shows then Vanishes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, markdown

I'm using code sample for my question 
[Is there a good Guitar Chord building web site?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/is-there-a-good-guitar-chord-building-web-site)
When I'm editing, the code/chord shows up correctly, when I actually view the question on the page, the code will show up, then vanish when the page finishes loading. I've tried this on both IE and Firefox.

Is there something I'm not doing correctly, or is this some strange bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anna Lear fixed it by making it proper jTab.

We're not a programming site, so our code blocks are actually jTab blocks.  If you want more or less the same effect as a code block on other sites, use `<pre>your stuff here</pre>`.